# Nginx - redirect non ssl & non www to ssl & www

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx

I've looked on Stack Overflow but every time I find a piece of code that people say would work, it unfortunately doesn't work for me.

I'm using Laravel on Forge and trying to redirect non www & non ssl to ssl+www.

It works. However, it does not redirect `https://example.com`. It redirects all other's: `example.com or www.example.com or http://example.com or http://www.example` to `https://www.example.com` except the one mentioned above.

I have no idea why this is happening.

Here's my Nginx file:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/21671/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/21671/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    #cache:
    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 168h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your first two servers only listen to the post 80 (non ssl).

Change them like this:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

 server {
    listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/21671/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/21671/server.key;
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue. Chrome shows this: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`. Maybe it's because I have to of the `listen 443` on my config file? Your's and the other one that I already had?

Comment: I forgot to add the certificates. It should work now, hopefully :)

Comment: Although it now redirects to https://www, I am now getting a redirection loop.  It says: `Too many redirects trying to open example.com...`